# How can I run development mode for React in an existing non-react website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cakephp

I have an admin panel built with CakePHP. We wanted to make some parts/ section of it more reactive than it is now. It was using JQuery before, but that is too much to manage. So I setup React inside the project, had an div element with specific ID attribute and then load a React component inside that div. and It works fine.
We would make a build of the project and then add the js file from the build folder inside CakePHP as script and that will load the project. But to make a build every time a change is made is too lengthy process to follow and debug. Running it directly in a new window works as usual React project but that's not what I am looking for. I want to use the session and CSRF token for api call.

I wanted to figure out how or even if it is possible to run development mode on React while it is integrated inside a non-react project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the whole question but AFAI understand, I think what you are looking for is hot-reloading. Most modern bundlers like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) comes with this functionality built-in. Or if you don't want to setup yourself, you can try AssetMix plugin(https://github.com/ishanvyas22/asset-mix).